# OnMessage in GCMBaseIntentService method called multiple time?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am doing sample PoC using GCM. I send the registration request to gcm server from my device and got the registration id for successful registration. I stored all the registration id in my app server database. I sent the data only one time to GCM from my app server to all my registration id. But, the OnMessage() method of GcmBaseIntentService called multiple time.

here is GCM response to my appserver when i am sending data

```
{
    "multicast_id": 5986417894970376000,
    "success": 7,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:1355230384617663%9fa953f8f9fd7ecd"
        },
        {
            "message_id": "0:1355230384617914%9fa953f8f9fd7ecd"
        },
        {
            "message_id": "0:1355230384617911%9fa953f8f9fd7ecd"
        },
        {
            "message_id": "0:1355230384617987%9fa953f8f9fd7ecd"
        },
        {
            "message_id": "0:1355230384617909%9fa953f8f9fd7ecd"
        },
        {
            "message_id": "0:1355230384617985%9fa953f8f9fd7ecd"
        },
        {
            "message_id": "0:1355230384618032%9fa953f8f9fd7ecd"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am doing some time taking task in my onMessage() method using AsynTask, Due to this multiple calls multiple thread getting created.

Please advice me on this issue.

Comment: Is it the same message being received by your app? It almost seems as though your app has registered multiple times. What are you sending to the GCM servers?

Comment: Yes the same message getting received. I just register only one time . From my appserver I am sending json response with api key as header and list of registration id ( right now its having only one id ) and some payload data.

Comment: Are you sure that you are only including one registrationID? I would unregister the app from GCM and your server, and then send the message again and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my server side code. Single registration id added multiple times in devices list of my payload data.